# Homomorphism binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

I always get a little bit confused when dealing with homomorphism questions and how to identify which binary operations needs to be used, for example I had the following question as homework

Is the following a homomorphism:

$\psi\colon \mathbb{C}^{\times}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$\psi (a+bi)=b$ (for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$)

I tried:

$\psi((a+bi)(c+di))= \psi((ac-bd)+i(bc+ad)) =bc+ad$

Then $\psi(a+bi)+\psi(c+di) =b+d$

Which would imply that it isn't a homomorphism however my teacher has informed me it is, have I used the wrong binary operation, and how do I know which one to use?

Comment: Please Latexify your questions.

Comment: Are you taking $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ to be a multiplicative group and the reals to be an additive group?

Comment: Yeah I am, is this where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the binary operations that turn the sets in question into group are essential to the solution. But in fact they are already essential to the *problem statement*. If we talk about groups, however, it is often clear which group operatin should be considered (unless explicitly specified differently). That is, for $\mathbb Z$,$\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ one may safely assume that addition is the intended binary operation (and surely not multiplication as $0$ does not have an inverse); and with $\mathbb Q^\times$, $\mathbb R^\times$ (or $\mathbb R_{>0}$) or $\mathbb C^\times$ one may safely assume that multiplication is intended (and not addition as that would be lacking the neutral element). So in cour case with a map $\mathbb C^\times\to\mathbb R$, your assumptions were fully justified - and correctly lead to the conclusion that $\psi$ is not a group homomorphism.